# Customizing port for nodejs application running on DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

For my personal website I used node.js and port 3000 to test my application on my box. To prevent the user from having to specify port 3000 when trying to access my website, how do I go about either customizing the port from my droplet or running my node.js application through the default port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lock remote access to port 3000 and use Nginx to forward request 80 to your nodejs program

Comment: As this answer suggests, I ended up using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04 to help me figure out how to install nginx and forward default port 80 traffic to port 3000.